# Creating objects for specific elements in a 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to retrieve two variables (e.g.: var4 and var5) by specifying the specific element in a 3D array.

I'm currently trying to do this by creating an object for the specific element, and then creating a class that retrieves the values for name4 and name5 based on the object specified by that specific element. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a class? and "retrieving" means you need a get() function as well as set() for "assigning"

Comment: `int test_3D_array[rows][columns][depth];` isn't standard c++.. Consider using a `std::vector`, may be best a single dimensional sectioned for dimension representation.

Comment: retrieve value from 3d array with object? I can't understand you too well.

Answer (score 1):

Your 3D container should be `private` inside the class. Then, your `set()` function will take `Row` `Column` `Depth` as parameters along with the actual `Value` you want to put in those coordinates or `indexes` and set it in the private container. Along with the `set()`, you need another function which is a `get()`. also `get()` should take three parameters which are the `indexes`, and it will retrieve the value from the private container for you.

Use this sample idea and you will see what happens.

```
set(row, column, depth, value); // can be void
RetrievedValue = get(row, column, depth) // should return something
```

This is a base code for a working code using `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Whatever
{
private:
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> MyVec; // 3D vector

public:
    Whatever(int RowSize, int ColumnSize, int DepthSize); // default constructor
    int get(int Row, int Column, int Depth);
    void set(int Row, int Column, int Depth, int Value);

};

Whatever::Whatever(int RowSize, int ColumnSize, int DepthSize)
{
    vector<int> TempDepth;
    vector<vector<int>> TempColumn;

    for (int i = 0; i < RowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ColumnSize; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < DepthSize; k++)
            {
                TempDepth.push_back(0); // add an integer zero to depth on every iteration
            } 
            TempColumn.push_back(TempDepth); // add the whole depth to the column
            TempDepth.clear(); // clear
        }
        this->MyVec.push_back(TempColumn); // add the whole column to the row
        TempColumn.clear(); // clear
    }
}


int Whatever::get(int Row, int Column, int Depth) 
{
    return this->MyVec[Row][Column][Depth]; // "get" the value from these indexes
}

void Whatever::set(int Row, int Column, int Depth, int Value)
{
    this->MyVec[Row][Column][Depth] = Value; // "set" the Value in these indexes

}


int main()
{
    int rowSize, columnSize, depthSize;

    cout << "Please enter your desired row size, column size and depth size:\n";
    cin >> rowSize >> columnSize >> depthSize;

    Whatever MyObjectOfClassWhatever(rowSize, columnSize, depthSize); // create a local object and send the sizes for it's default constructor

    // let's say you need "set" a value in [2][4][1]
    MyObjectOfClassWhatever.set(2, 4, 1, 99);

    // now you want to "get" a value in [2][4][1]
    int RetreivedData = MyObjectOfClassWhatever.get(2, 4, 1); // you get it from within the class and assign it to a local variable

    // now you can do whatever you want

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments! FirstStep, could you give me a bit more detailed example of how I could use "set" and "get"? I'm very new with regard to classes (as you can probably tell from my humble code example), so any clarifications would be great!

Comment: See my edited post. Please mark solutions on your StackOverflow questions as ANSWERS once you get it.